# How to display a div that needs to expand in IE with no width set

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

```
<container>
    <element1>
    </element1>
    <element2>
    </element2>
</container>
```

---

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    right:33px;
    top:15px;
}

#element1 {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:31px;
    background:url(../main_bg.gif) repeat-x top left;
    border: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
    clear:both;
}

#element2 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#f8f0ce;
    border-left:1px solid #6a6a6a;
    border-right:1px solid #6a6a6a;
    border-bottom:1px solid #6a6a6a;
}
```

Comment: A div element will automatically expand width-ways if it is not floating. If it is floating, it cannot expand without a width. You didn't put any description of your problem in your question, so I am somewhat guessing as to what you require.

Comment: I want the container div to expand based upon the information inside. In IE the contiainer automatically is expanding the width of the page and not based upon the width of the content. In all other browsers, the container is only as wide as the information inside.

Comment: If your container's `display` is either `inline` or `inline-block` it will only expand to what is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `container` seems to be displayed as wide as it content in other browser is because it is out of the "body" and displayed in "nothing" (ence, as wide as its content). IE6/7 seems to treat this differently.

I do not have your issue in IE8, so I suppose you want this for IE6 or 7. It also seems you want 2 box, one under each other (`clear`).

From the code and the style you supplied, it seems we could simply get rid of the floating and put a text-align:right.

Would [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/X23Ne/2/) work for you?

It does not work in IE6 however.

[This one does however](http://jsfiddle.net/X23Ne/2/), but require a `<br />` (and `display:inline`. Thanks @kei for the suggestion.)